# Nativescript-vue + Typescript - HMR not working on Vue Class Component

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

**Environment**

- CLI: 6.5.0
- Cross-platform modules: 6.5.1
- Android Runtime: 6.5.0
- iOS Runtime: 6.5.0

**Describe the bug**

When saving any file with vue class component style + typescript, It simply does not update. Give me the following error:

```
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...
Successfully transferred bundle.609c813aedb0d81fb57e.hot-update.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred 609c813aedb0d81fb57e.hot-update.json on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash 609c813aedb0d81fb57e.
JS: HMR: Ignored an update to unaccepted module: 
JS: HMR:          ➭ ./routes.ts
JS: HMR:          ➭ ./main.ts
JS: HMR: Cannot apply update with hmr hash 609c813aedb0d81fb57e.
JS: HMR: Aborted because ./routes.ts is not accepted
JS: Update propagation: ./routes.ts -> ./main.ts
Refreshing application on device emulator-5554...
Successfully transferred bundle.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred vendor.js on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Cannot apply update. A previous update aborted. Application needs to be restarted in order to apply the changes.
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
```

This causes the entire application to restart, with no HRM update.

**To Reproduce**

Base on nativescript blogs [NativeScript-Vue with Class Components](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-vue-with-class-components)
***More samples on the link.***

1. npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init
2. vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template hmrbug. (Select Typescript)
3. npm i vue-class-component
4. npm i vue-property-decorator

Next:
Create the following template:

`<Label text="Hello" textWrap="true" />`

Then add a hello to the text

`<Label text="Hello Hello" textWrap="true" />`

Check the error.

**Expected behavior**

Use the famous HMR without restarting the entire App. I consider this a severe problem or bug, since it slows down your productivity as developer while waiting to the app to restart.

Comment: I think this goes to Github issues, I believe there are known issues with Vue + HMR, I would suggest you to disable HMR (`--no-hmr`). Of course it's less productive but better than getting struck in the middle of HMR reload every here and then.

Comment: Thank you, I think i will continue using --no-hmr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Please use `tns debug android --no-hmr`

In nativescript-vue and HMR is not guarantied. HMR can be used only while making changes in style files.

#### My personal use

I use `tns debug android` only for styling. If I make any other change I do not trust HMR.

I have added a yarn script called `yarn devan` to speed up typing process.

I have added following lines to my package.json file

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tns debug android",
    "devan": "tns debug android --no-hmr",
    "devin": "tns debug ios --no-hmr",
    "un": "adb uninstall com.domain.yourapp"
  },
}
```

---

You will always see HMR error message if you use typescipt files in nativescript-vue projects.

```bash
JS: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash 7d5f6392d6103f1496e6.
JS:  WARN  HMR: Ignored an update to unaccepted module: 
JS:  WARN  HMR:          ➭ ./routes/index.ts
JS:  WARN  HMR:          ➭ ./main.ts
JS:  ERROR  HMR: Cannot apply update with hmr hash 7d5f6392d6103f1496e6.
JS:  ERROR  HMR: Aborted because ./routes/index.ts is not accepted
JS: Update propagation: ./routes/index.ts -> ./main.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!! . It is disappointing that nativescript does not have HRM with vue yet :C.

Answer (score 0):

I got my Nativescript-Vue + Typescript with HMR project working.Just take note (according to rigor himself, the creator of NS-Vue) that its best to enable HMR when working with styles.

Here is the issue and the thread that solved my problem: https://github.com/Lyduz/nitibo/issues/19